# Insert Google authorship into WordPress header

Tags: actions, wp-head

I'm working on a custom plugin that creates courses and lessons within WordPress. Here's the page I'm trying to get Google authorship showing in:
→ http://myguitarpal.com/videos/?lesson_id=13

Google authorship needs to be in every lesson and should be in the header. It's the same author for every lesson.

I thought it would be as simple as adding this to the `lessons.php` file, but it's not.  Nothing shows up when I view the source.

```
<?php
    function google_authorship(){
        echo '<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/authorname">';
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'google_authorship');
?>
```

I'm assuming it's because `header.php` is loaded before this block of code runs and the action hook doesn't get hooked. I checked our theme and `wp_head()` is in `header.php`.

I guess I could modify the `header.php` file and do:

```
<?php
    is_page('videos'){
        echo '<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/authorname">';
    }
?>
```

But I don't want to modify the theme if I don't have to. There must be a way to add code to the header from within a plugin. Is there? After a lot of searching, I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess, because you didn't provide (parts of) your template.

Anyway, most probably (if `lessons.php` is a *full* template) there is `get_header();` somewhere at the beginning of your template file.
If you put the very code you posted in your question **before** this it will render, as the `wp_head` action is still to come.

**// EDIT**
My suggestion, however, is to put the function in your `functions.php`. Then you'd have to adapt it to your needs, of course. But this approach is much more powerful (if you need this, that is). You could do things like this:

```
function wpdev_156346_wp_head() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Some logged-in-user stuff
    }

    if ( is_search() ) {

        // Some search-only stuff

    } elseif ( is_singular() ) {

        switch ( get_post_type() ) {
            case 'page':
                // Some page-only stuff...
                break;

            case 'video':
                // Some video-only stuff...
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpdev_156346_wp_head' );
```

Comment: It's actually not done in a page template.  It's all called with a shortcode into a page post.  I'm guessing because of that it would make the most sense to just put the code in functions.php  Your response does help me understand some things much better though.

Comment: _Template_ not only refers to **page** template. (Almost) All the PHP files your theme consists of are templates (cf. [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)).